# What are the recommended base memory and processors for Ubuntu?

Tags: virtualbox

I am looking forward to creating a virtual machine to try out ubuntu.

I installed the image file from the main Ubuntu website, and install virtual box on my machine.
I want to know what the recommended base memory and processors for my VM is.

I will use the VM on daily bases for front-end coding, and Python.

This is my device specifications:

```
Device name DESKTOP-BJ9CEB4
Processor   11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz   2.40 GHz
Installed RAM   16.0 GB (15.7 GB usable)
Device ID   23AB3791-3FAD-4014-9605-C0B6F7D0F9DB
Product ID  00342-20713-03519-AAOEM
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   No pen or touch input is available for this display
```

I want that the VM run fast and smooth, also I want the main pc which is running Windows 11 to run smooth to.

Thanks.

Comment: Start with 4GB RAM, 40 GB disk and 2 Processors. You can increase RAM and processors easily later.

Comment: Thank you @FedKad I will try it